# ScrollPane containing ImageView does not update its scrollbars after calling setImage()

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I am experimenting JavaFX with a simple image viewer. I want it to display an image and, if it does not fit in the window, display scrollbars. The image to dislay is loaded with the `FileChooser` and set to the `ImageView` using `imageView.setImage(image)`.

The problem is that the scrollbars of the containing `ScrollPane` *do not* update after calling `imageView.setImage(image)`. Instead, I need to perform an action that changes the scene (e.g. resize the window). It behaves the same when an image is displayed and another is loaded, i.e. the sizes of the scrollbars reflect the size of the previous image.

---

The bug is reproducible using the following cut-down version of the code:

(Java)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ImageViewerBug extends Application
{
    @FXML private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ImageViewerBug.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try {
            BorderPane borderPane = (BorderPane) fxmlLoader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch( IOException e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void loadClicked() {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        File f = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if( f != null ) {
            try( InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f) ) {
                Image image = new Image(is);
                imageView.setImage(image);
            }
            catch( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

(FXML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<BorderPane id="BorderPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <center>
    <ScrollPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
      <content>
        <Group>
          <ImageView fx:id="imageView" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
        </Group>
      </content>
    </ScrollPane>
  </center>
  <top>
    <ToolBar>
      <items>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadClicked" text="Load" />
      </items>
    </ToolBar>
  </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm this bug. A quick and dirty workaround that fixed it for me:

```
    public void loadClicked() {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    File f = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if( f != null ) {
        try( InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f) ) {
            Image image = new Image(is);
            imageView.setImage(image);
            imageView.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), new WritableImage(1, 1));
            double rnd = new Random().nextInt(10);
            imageView.setX(rnd/1000);
            imageView.setY(rnd/1000);
        }
        catch( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The `snapshot()` Method sometimes works like a charm whenever some UI-element isn't updated or displayed correctly. But don't ask me why that works, maybe it has something to do with the rendering process, because `snapshots` forces JavaFX to render the scene graph or the target elements. The random stuff is needed to create the right scrollbar sizes when adding a new image after one already part of the `ImageView`. 
Maybe this has something to do with the [strange behaviour i found some weeks earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282403/wrong-results-when-trying-to-get-sizes-of-a-pane-with-css-formattings). The workaround also solved my problems back then.

**(Really late)EDIT**

The problem is caused by the `Group` which wraps the `ImageView`. If you use a node that inherits from `Pane` the behaviour of the `ScrollPane` should be as expected even without the workaround. A `Group` can still be used as the direct child of the `ScrollPane` as long as a `Pane` wraps the `ImageView`.

Example:

```
<ScrollPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
  <content>
    <Group id="Group">
      <children>
        <HBox id="HBox" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="0.0" layoutY="0.0" spacing="5.0">
          <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="imageView" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
          </children>
        </HBox>
      </children>
    </Group>
  </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. I cannot accept this (at least for now) since I believe there should be a non-workaround solution (and hope to find one). By the way however, do you know what would be the performance impact of the snapshot?

Comment: I did not see the edit in time; yes I can confirm that the addition of the `HBox` solves the problem. Additionally the problem seems to have **gone away in JavaFX 8**. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem with image...Instead of

```
Image image = new Image(is);
```

You should write:

```
Image image = new Image("file:" + ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_FILE);
```

Image will refresh automatically, you don't have to do anything. For me, it works

Answer (score 0):

use the command:

```
Scrollbar scrollbar
// ...
// Some activities with children that extends canvas, so scrollbar is needed.
// ...    
scrollbar.layout();
```

this will update your scrollbar.
No Workaround needed.