# ScrollPane is not refreshing its contents

Tags: java, javafx, mouse, viewport, scrollpane

### RESUME

Good day StackOverflow community.

I've been trying for some time to develop a program that enables users to put objects in an area, allowing this area to be moved by the mouse. For this type of program, I decided to use a ScrollPane, because the user can add various contents in the area which I call the canvas. For some reason, something strange is happening in my program.

### EXPLANATION OF PROGRAM

What I basically did was create a group of objects, and define this group as the ScrollPane content. Within the group, there is a Rectangle object that was added to serve as canvas boundaries. This object has larger dimensions (such as 1500 x 1000, for example), and is used in calculations that prevent nodes from moving beyond its limits. This is just the logical behind the existing large rectangle in my program, but in reality, there is no Node object with the mouse movement. What exists is the random distribution of Shape objects by the rectangle area.

For ScrollPane has its scrollbars moved, I use the [setHvalue](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#setHvalue-double-) [setVvalue](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#setVvalue-double-) methods. Unfortunately for my purposes, this method does not change the position of the ScrollPane's viewport with pixel values​​, but values ​​that are in a range between 0f and 1f. So I can move the viewport with the mouse, I used a equation known as Rule of 3 (here in my Country, as I know), which we equate values ​​and cross multiply.

For example, say I want to move the viewport of the ScrollPane with the mouse horizontally, and that my canvas area has a width of 2000 pixels. Finding how far (in pixels) the mouse was dragged from one point to another, I need to know how this value represents in a range 0f to 1f. Suppose I have dragged the mouse in 3 pixels, I could find the representation of the 0f to 1f with the following comparison:

```
2000 px ---- 1f
   3 px ---- xf
```

Multiplying crossed, I'll get the following result:

```
xf = 3 / 2000
xf = 0.0015
```

> **Note**: I believe you all know that. I'm not teaching math to anyone,
>   just want to explain the logic of my problem.

### SOURCE CODE

Here is my program class:

```
import testes.util.TestesUtil;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScrollTest4 extends Application
{
// #########################################################################################################
//                                                                                                      MAIN
// #########################################################################################################

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Application.launch(args);
}

// #########################################################################################################
//                                                                                                INSTÂNCIAS
// #########################################################################################################

// OUTSIDE

private BorderPane root;
private Button but_moreH;
private Button but_lessH;
private Button but_moreV;
private Button but_lessV;

// LOG

private VBox vbox_south;
private Label lab_hValue;
private Label lab_vValue;
private Label lab_viewport;

// INSIDE

private Rectangle rec_canvas;
private ScrollPane scroll;
private Group grp_objects;

// MOUSE

private double mouse_x = 0;
private double mouse_y = 0;

// MISC

private AnimationTimer timer;

// EDITED - 08/02/2014
private boolean moreH = false;
private boolean moreV = false;  // Purposely unused.
private boolean lessH = false;
private boolean lessV = false;  // Purposely unused.

// #########################################################################################################
//                                                                                                 INÍCIO FX
// #########################################################################################################

@Override public void start(Stage estagio) throws Exception 
{
    this.iniFX();
    this.confFX();
    this.adFX();
    this.evFX();

    Scene cenario = new Scene(this.root , 640 , 480);

    estagio.setScene(cenario);
    estagio.setTitle("Programa JavaFX");
    estagio.show();
}

protected void iniFX()
{
    // OUTSIDE

    this.root = new BorderPane();
    this.but_moreH = new Button();
    this.but_lessH = new Button();
    this.but_moreV = new Button();
    this.but_lessV = new Button();

    // LOG

    this.vbox_south = new VBox();
    this.lab_hValue = new Label();
    this.lab_vValue = new Label();
    this.lab_viewport = new Label();

    // INSIDE

    this.scroll = new ScrollPane();
    this.grp_objects = new Group();
    this.rec_canvas = new Rectangle();

    // MISC

    this.timer = new AnimationTimer()
    {
        @Override public void handle(long now) 
        {
            // EDITED - 08/02/2014
            if(but_moreH.isArmed() || moreH)
            {
                // scroll.hvalueProperty().set(scroll.hvalueProperty().get() + 0.003f);
                scroll.setHvalue(scroll.getHvalue() + 0.003f);
            }
            // EDITED - 08/02/2014
            if(but_lessH.isArmed() || lessH)
            {
                // scroll.hvalueProperty().set(scroll.hvalueProperty().get() - 0.003f);
                scroll.setHvalue(scroll.getHvalue() - 0.003f);
            }
            if(but_moreV.isArmed())
            {
                scroll.setVvalue(scroll.getVvalue() + 0.003f);
            }
            if(but_lessV.isArmed())
            {
                scroll.setVvalue(scroll.getVvalue() - 0.003f);
            }
        }
    };
    this.timer.start();
}

protected void confFX() 
{
    // OUTSIDE

    this.but_moreH.setText("More H");
    this.but_moreH.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);

    this.but_lessH.setText("Less H");
    this.but_lessH.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);

    this.but_moreV.setText("More V");
    this.but_moreV.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

    this.but_lessV.setText("Less V");
    this.but_lessV.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

    // LOG

    this.updateHvalue();
    this.updateVvalue();
    this.updateViewport();

    // INSIDE

    this.rec_canvas.setWidth(1200);
    this.rec_canvas.setHeight(1000);
    this.rec_canvas.setFill(Color.INDIANRED);
    this.rec_canvas.setStroke(Color.RED);
    this.rec_canvas.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);
    this.rec_canvas.setStrokeWidth(1);
}

protected void adFX() 
{
    // LOG

    this.vbox_south.getChildren().add(this.but_moreV);
    this.vbox_south.getChildren().addAll(this.lab_hValue , this.lab_vValue , this.lab_viewport);

    // OUTSIDE

    this.root.setCenter(this.scroll);
    this.root.setTop(this.but_lessV);
    this.root.setBottom(this.vbox_south);
    this.root.setRight(this.but_moreH);
    this.root.setLeft(this.but_lessH);

    // INSIDE

    this.grp_objects.getChildren().add(this.rec_canvas);
    this.scroll.setContent(this.grp_objects);

    // MISC

    StrokeType[] strokes = {StrokeType.CENTERED , StrokeType.INSIDE , StrokeType.OUTSIDE};

    for(int cont = 0 ; cont < 20 ; cont++)
    {
        Rectangle node = new Rectangle(Math.random() * 100 + 50 , Math.random() * 100 + 50);
        node.setFill(TestesUtil.getCorAleatoria(false));
        node.setStroke(TestesUtil.getCorAleatoria(false));
        node.setStrokeType(strokes[(int) (Math.random() * 2)]);
        node.setStrokeWidth(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
        node.setRotate(Math.random() * 360);
        node.setMouseTransparent(true);

        // EDITED - 08/02/2014
        TestsUtil.putRandomlyIn(
                node , 
                rec_canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() ,
                rec_canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() + rec_canvas.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() , 
                rec_canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() + rec_canvas.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() , 
                rec_canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() );

        this.grp_objects.getChildren().add(node);
    }
}

protected void evFX() 
{
    // ##########################
    //     SCROLL PROPERTIES
    // ##########################

    this.scroll.hvalueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>()
    {
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,Number oldValue, Number newValue) 
        {
            updateHvalue();
            updateViewport();
        }
    });

    this.scroll.vvalueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>()
    {
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,Number oldValue, Number newValue) 
        {
            updateVvalue();
            updateViewport();
        }
    });

    this.scroll.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
    {
        @Override public void handle(KeyEvent e) 
        {
            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT)
            {
                moreH = true;
            }
            else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT)
            {
                lessH = true;
            }
        }
    });

    this.scroll.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
    {
        @Override public void handle(KeyEvent e) 
        {
            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT)
            {
                moreH = false;
            }
            else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT)
            {
                lessH = false;
            }
        }
    });

    // ##########################
    //          CANVAS
    // ##########################

    this.rec_canvas.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            // The XY distance from the upper left corner of the canvas.
            mouse_x = e.getX();
            mouse_y = e.getY();
        }
    });

    this.rec_canvas.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            // ##########################
            //           PIXELS 
            // ##########################

            // The distance between mouse movements (drag events).
            double xPixelsMoved = e.getX() - mouse_x;
            // double yPixelsMoved = e.getY() - mouse_y;

            // ##########################
            //           TO 1F
            // ##########################

            double h_of_1f = xPixelsMoved / rec_canvas.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
            double h_of_1f_inverted = h_of_1f * -1;

            double currentH = scroll.getHvalue();
            scroll.setHvalue(currentH + h_of_1f);

            // scroll.hvalueProperty().set(scroll.getHvalue() + h_de_x);
            // scroll.vvalueProperty().set(scroll.getVvalue() + v_de_y);

            // ##########################
            //           DEBUG
            // ##########################

            System.out.printf("xPixelsMoved: %f , h_of_1f: %f , h_of_1f_inverted: %f %n", 
                    xPixelsMoved , h_of_1f , h_of_1f_inverted);

            // ##########################
            //        UPDATE FROM 
            //       EVENT TO EVENT
            // ##########################

            // Writes last mouse position to update on new motion event.
            mouse_x = e.getX();
            mouse_y = e.getY();
        }
    });
}

// #########################################################################################################
//                                                                                                     MISC.
// #########################################################################################################

protected void updateViewport()
{
    Bounds vport = this.scroll.getViewportBounds();
    this.lab_viewport.setText(String.format("Viewport - [X: %f , Y: %f , W: %f , H: %f]", 
            vport.getMinX() , vport.getMinY() , vport.getWidth() , vport.getHeight() ));
}

protected void updateHvalue()
{
    this.lab_hValue.setText("H value: " + this.scroll.getHvalue() );
}

protected void updateVvalue()
{
    this.lab_vValue.setText("V value: " + this.scroll.getVvalue() );
}
```

}

### THE PROBLEM

Clicking the mouse button on the canvas area and drag it, you can see that the program moves the ScrollPane viewport horizontally. The program seems to work perfectly (or not). However, something goes wrong at the time when the mouse is dragged sometimes abruptly (...or not!). At certain times the ScrollPane Viewport is not visually updated. This is a strange behavior, because even if viewport is not visually updated, the scrollbars are still updated.

I put other ways to move the ScrollPane viewport horizontally using the same method, and for some reason, only the approach using the mouse makes it happen. I thought this could be solved by making a request for layout using [requestLayout](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/Parent.html#requestLayout--), also causing a request to a pulse, but it does not work.

### THE TEST OUTPUT

The odd thing is that everything returns to normal when the window of my application is resized. Here's a video that shows what happens to my program:

[VIDEO](http://videobam.com/IDGyf) & [MIRROR 1](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=sws4jq%3E&s=8#.UvUFzIUUFsI)

I no longer know what else to do. Can anyone help me with this please?

### EDIT (08/02/2014 10:08 AM GMT - 3:00)

The original source code of my application is found written in Portuguese, so you may be seeing something unknown. Basically TestesUtil is a utility class with static methods that define shortcuts to other client classes. I changed the call from my source code shown here previously and am now putting some methods of my class TestesUtil, translated into English as TestsUtil:

```
public static void putRandomlyIn(Node node , double northPoint , double southPoint , double eastPoint , double westPoint)
{
    node.setLayoutX(Math.random() * pontoLeste);
    node.setLayoutY(Math.random() * pontoSul);

    fixEasternBoundary(node , eastPoint);
    fixNorthernBoundary(node , northPoint);
    fixWesternBoundary(node , westPoint);
    fixSouthernBoundary(node , southPoint);
}
```

There is no mystery here. This method simply calculates a value from an interval, and defines the LayoutXY properties for the Node argument. Methods "fix ..." just check the boundsInParent bounds of the node compared to the point in the argument, and then adjust the layoutXYproperties from the Node object. Even if I remove the random distribution of objects, the problem still happens. So I'm sure this problem is not being caused by this.

The source code of the original post was changed with the addition of the ability to move the scroll bars with the arrow keys. Even if it is already an existing function of ScrollPane, adding that could reproduce the error seen with the mouse (now with arrows). Some things were also translated into English for better understanding by the community.

Please, I ask for help. I'm getting dizzy not knowing what to do. This type of situation could be happening because of some bug in JavaFX? Ahhrr... Please somebody help me in this. :'(

Thank you for your attention anyway.

### EDIT (09/02/2014 10:50 AM GMT - 3:00)

Forgot to mention... My program was initially written and tested using JDK 8 b123. Currently I installed the JDK 8 b128 version and am still getting the same problem. My operating system is Windows 7 64x.

I am almost certain that this is a bug. Are you guys getting the same result as me? Or am I the only one to find this kind of problem? If this is a bug, which procedure should be taken?

Thank you for your attention.

### EDIT (10/02/2014 09:45 AM GMT - 3:00)

A bounty was started.

Comment: Where is TestesUtil class file in your project

Comment: @Reegan I edited my original post. Please check it. Thank you for your attention. :')

Comment: I tried your code and can confirm this weird behavior for Windows 7: When running your example with JRE 8 b128 32 bit the cursor-scrolling gets disabled, if one does randomly move the cursor around the screen very fast for some time. After resizing the frame, it suddenly works again. Using JDK 1.7.0_51 your example works fine on the other hand. So this is certainly a bug that should be reported to the JavaFX developers. I can only suggest using JDK 7 until this bug is fixed. Good luck - and btw: Very nice problem description with lot of effort put in!

Comment: @Balder Thank you, Balder. I think this is the kind of thing we programmers must share so that we can develop better and functional applications. I'm more than a week with this problem. I considered several alternatives, all of which would result in something poorly done and not maintainable. Unfortunately, I need to use JDK 8, because I can use the new CSS API. I'm completely clueless about how to notify the JavaFX developers about the bug. Actually, I do not know if this is a bug. I believe it can be, but I can not say.

Comment: If this problem is actually considered a bug, I will consider as correct an answer that shows that this is a bug, and JavaFX developers were notified. I really want this to be solved in the future because I really need to use this feature (as all of us). The JDK 8 is scheduled to be completed and delivered in mid-2014. Until then, I hope this is resolved. But again I say ... I still do not know if this is a bug. It is necessary that it be notified to JavaFX developers. I also created a [discussion](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3514028) in the Oracle community. So far, nothing.

Comment: I added a bug description and a hacky workaround for the problem in my answer. But you should really report the bug yourself because you are much more involved with it and with JavaFX. Of course feel free to use parts of my description as you see fit. You can report the bug here: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa. Also link to this diskussion, perhaps some other users can also confirm it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This bug has now been fixed for JavaFX 8u20.

**Bug description**

This is a bug, that can be easily verified by executing the following code with JavaFx JRE 8:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

final ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
final Image[] images = new Image[5];
final ImageView[] pics = new ImageView[5];
final VBox vb = new VBox();
final Label fileName = new Label();
final String [] imageNames = new String [] {"fw1.jpg", "fw2.jpg",
        "fw3.jpg", "fw4.jpg", "fw5.jpg"};

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    VBox box = new VBox();
    Scene scene = new Scene(box, 180, 180);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Scroll Pane");
    box.getChildren().addAll(sp, fileName);
    VBox.setVgrow(sp, Priority.ALWAYS);

    fileName.setLayoutX(30);
    fileName.setLayoutY(160);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageNames[i]));
        pics[i] = new ImageView(images[i]);
        pics[i].setFitWidth(100);
        pics[i].setPreserveRatio(true);
        vb.getChildren().add(pics[i]);
    }

    sp.setVmax(440);
    sp.setPrefSize(115, 150);
    sp.setContent(vb);
    sp.vvalueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
            Number old_val, Number new_val) {
                fileName.setText(imageNames[(new_val.intValue() - 1)/100]);
        }
    });

    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

This code comes directly from the [JavaFX ScrollPane Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/scrollpane.htm).

If one randomly moves the vertical scroll bar with the mouse very rapidly, then at some time the screen will freeze and no longer get updated. Although one is still able to move the scroll bar around, the displayed images will stay fixed. Only if one resizes the frame, the display of the images will be updated and the ScrollPane reverts to its previous state. Note, that this bug will only happen in JRE 8, it is not reproducible in JRE 7.

The only workaround for the problem, that I could find, is adding

```
sp.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), new WritableImage(1, 1));
```

to the listener:

```
    sp.vvalueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
            Number old_val, Number new_val) {
                fileName.setText(imageNames[(new_val.intValue() - 1)/100]);
                sp.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), new WritableImage(1, 1));
        }
    });
```

Calling snapshot on the ScrollPane seems to force the update every time the vvalueProperty changes. This seems to be a known workaround for several update problems with JavaFX - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610950/scrollpane-containing-imageview-does-not-update-its-scrollbars-after-calling-set).

Comment: I created a new issue in JIRA system. I do not know if I did correctly because I do not really know how to use JIRA. I think the problem has not yet responded. Could you tell me if I did right? You could also tell me what should I do now? What I want, as I said, is that the problem is seen by developers, and it is eventually resolved. If so, I will consider this issue as something of the past, and I'll be calm. I need to have that certainty. The link to the open issue is here: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-35783?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Comment: I just exchanged some comments with Jonathan Giles at JIRA and after some initial problems, he was able to reproduce the bug. He said he will look into it.

Comment: @Loa "You could also tell me what should I do now?" I would suggest to watch the bug progress and use the workaround I mentioned above, until it gets fixed. Do not expect too much from the JavaFX developers - hunting down a bug like this can take some time...

Comment: I have no words to describe how I'm thanking you for helping me. Balder, thank you. You not only helped me but also made ​​a greater effort to get my problem resolved. I am happy that this community has people like you. I conclude this issue as a real bug in the JavaFX language. The developers themselves have recognized this and are now in the process of resolution.

Comment: I found it interesting the alternative approach you suggested, but it seemed a bit dirty, and may affect the performance of my application. For now, there's nothing to do. I'll need to wait until this bug is resolved. Again I thank you for everything, you are a good person. :)

Comment: Thanks Loa, I'm glad I was able to help. Incredible how fast the JavaFX developers are working - I just saw, that they have already traced the bug back to the issues.

Comment: @Loa On a side note: not that I want to be greedy, but since you accepted my answer - would you perhaps also consider awarding me the open bounty? I believe you have forgotten...

Comment: Ah! I'm sorry! This is the first time I create a bounty. I thought I just needed to put your answer as correct. Forgive me.